# Ansible - how to control the order of the hosts when playbook is ran

Tags: ansible

Let's say that we have defined two machines in our inventory file:

`[db-server-preprod]
 172.16.0.1
 172.16.0.2`

If I run a playbook against this group will run in the same time on both machines if serial is 0 or sequentially if is 1 and the order seems to be the one in which the IPs are defined in the group.

**But the question is if can I control the order of the playbook execution on the defined machines?**

The same role behaves slightly different for one of the machines (the master) as opposed to all the others but is important that the machine that I want to be the master will be the first one on which the playbook executes.

My ideas so far:

- create different group names in which the order of the IPs is reversed and based on needs run on one host or another but the disadvantage is that I think I would need to duplicate group_vars so there will be one for each `db-server-preprod*` variant + all the other environments.
- separate the installation on two different roles - one for master and for standby servers and based on the needs I will run the one that I want on which machine I want.

Comment: Try a pre_task dynamic group https://stackoverflow.com/a/45302096/516748

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may place your master host into separate group, then apply common role to all servers at once, then apply master-roles only to master server, and slave-roles to all servers except master using excluding pattern.

Inventory:

```
[all-servers]
host1
host2
host3
host4

[master-server]
host2
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all-servers
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=role-common

- hosts: master-server
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=role-master

- hosts: all-servers:!master-server
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=role-slave
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not only this answer my questions - because I thought something similar but now I found out that a playbook is actually a list of plays - which is very cool and useful for me - until this point I only created playbooks that contained a single play not knowing you can put more of them as a list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use in the playbook `main.yml` "serial = 1" so it executes one by one, and you can ensure that the playbook would execute on the master node and after that it would execute on the others nodes.

```
- hosts: allnodes
  remote_user: "{{user}}"
  become: True
  serial: 1
  roles:
  - role: your_role
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this was exactly my current situation - I use serial: 1 and I am relying on the fact that the order is the one defined in the inventory file for the current group. And the question was how to control that a machine where I want to install the master (even if not the first in inventory) will be the first one but I guess is not possible so I might go with the answer from Konstantin.

Comment: I am doing exactly that, to pick master: *{{ hostvars[groups[env][0]].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0] }}*
if ip matches this, its master, all others are slaves.