# Selecting only 1 node in ansible group

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible inventory file that looks like:

```
[database]
172.29.225.95 is_master=true
172.29.225.93 is_master=false
172.29.225.94 is_master=false
```

I want to run my playbook ONLY on the master node which is `172.29.225.95` but is there a way in Ansible to simply select one node that I want to run the playbook on ?

There is a dirty hack that Ive tried. Its simply to add a new entry in my inventory file and use that group only.

```
[database-master]
172.29.225.95
```

and then

```
- name: Perform Health Checks.
  hosts: database-master
  tasks:
    - name: Check Postgres cluster status.
      shell: /usr/efm-2.0/bin/efm cluster-status efm
      register: output
```

But I feel this is just a work around and not a solid solution. So working ONLY with `[database]` group, can I make Ansible just run the playbook only on `172.29.225.95` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using real IPs. Especially since you are explicitly stating the host as 'database-master' O_O

Comment: If you can refactor your inventory, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42387143/2795592).

Comment: "*can I make Ansible just run the playbook only on*" -- a playbook is a YAML file containing a list of plays, you don't  run playbooks on any target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you could use the --limit option of ansible-playbook executable as [described in documentation](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible/commands/#limit-to-one-or-more-hosts)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the *run_once* option on your task. This tells your playbook to run the task only on the first host of your group. If you have a specific host on which this should run you can combine it with *delegate_to*

So in your example this would look something like this, whereas database-master is just a placeholder for you master's hostname:

```
tasks:
  - name: Check Postgres cluster status.
    shell: /usr/efm-2.0/bin/efm cluster-status efm
    run_once: true
    delegate_to: database-master 
    register: output
```

See also official [ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop with a condition on your `hostvars` (now being new to ansible, not sure if it satisfies your requirement, or even if doing this is a good idea)

With the following inventory:

```
[tests]
localhost is_master=true
test is_master=false
```

And a simple playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: some_user

  tasks:
    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "Host is {{item}}"
      with_items: "{{groups['tests']}}"
      when: ("{{hostvars[item]['is_master']}}"=="true")
```

The output of the task (with -vvv):

```
TASK [test] ********************************************************************
task path: /home/sa-1t40-app-i/AnsibleTest/test.yml:12
ok: [localhost] => (item=localhost) => {
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "msg": "Host is localhost"
        },
        "module_name": "debug"
    },
    "item": "localhost",
    "msg": "Host is localhost"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=test)  => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": "test",
    "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
    "skipped": true
}
```